# Cycle through a list of items to ensure a different slug?

Tags: php, slug

I know this has been done before. You can see an example of it whenever you post a new blog post/page in Wordpress, and the title is the same title as an existing page/post. Here's an example:

- some-page-slug
- some-page-slug-1
- some-page-slug-2

How would you programmatically (using PHP) deal with someone submitting the slug of "some-page-slug" with the given list. Obviously, you should result in "some-page-slug-3", but what does that code look like? For some reason, this escapes me. I'm assuming, and hopefully I'm wrong, you would have to use jQuery (or vanilla js, whatever), correct?

Comment: Try researching and trying something first. We can then help with the code you have that isn't working.

Comment: @nevermind That wouldn't work. If there is slug1, slug2 and slug3 existing and you go to add slug1, if you +1 it would result in slug2 which also exists. Although, based on that though you could do a while loop that checks and every time it sees that it exists it add's 1 until it doesn't exist, then it submits to the database.

Comment: @MathewMacLean I've already tried building something awhile back. If you need that code, that's something else, but yes, I've already tried this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution like [Mathew MacLeans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3009513/mathew-maclean) suggested in his comment:

```
$slug = 'slug';
$slugs = array('slug', 'slug-1', 'slug-2', 'slug-5');
$result = $slug;

$i = 1;
while(in_array($result, $slugs)) {
    $result = $slug . '-' . $i;
    ++$i;
}

// prints 'slug-3'
print $result;
```

Of course you have to replace `in_array` with your function that checks for existence of a slug.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepad.org/OOzSlAV8)

Comment: I like yours, I wonder if he is using an array or mysql for this? I would assume posts would be stored in a database. I posted my answer but it's nothing more than Pseudo code.

Comment: @MathewMacLean Right - he could either load all slugs for that menu level at once into an array and check them like in the example code (*1 MySQL request*) or he could try to load each new `$result` slug and see whether it exists (*1…n MySQL requests*).

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Your method is much more efficient

Comment: The array works for me, for many reasons, I like it. I can always dump the SQL into an array, which is essentially what I do anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Just some pseudo-code to get you going, but I believe this is the route you should take.

```
$postTitle = <WhateverTheTitleIs>;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE title = '$postTitle'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
     // title not found, submit to database
} else {
    // title exists
    $postTitle = $postTitle + 1;   
}
```

Now, obviously this isn't anywhere near 100% correct syntax, but it should more than point you in the direction that you need to go. :)

Comment: I haven't tried that code above, but by simply understanding it, here's the problem. It's not looping through titles/slugs to ensure that "title + 1" is not already present, like my initial question demonstrates.

Comment: You are right. You could always add a while loop in there instead.